# Power BI - SQL query with Case When to DAX?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I am trying to convert a below SQL query into DAX on my Power BI Report.

SQL QUERY: -

```
select  Date
       ,Id
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN fkid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as rflag
       ,MAX(CASE WHEN fkid = 128 then 1 else 0 end) as dflag
       ,CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN fkid = 1 then 1 else 0 end) = 1 AND MAX(CASE WHEN fkid = 128 then 1 else 0 end)=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS BOTH
from table
GROUP BY Date,Id
```

INPUT TABLE: -

```
DATE        ID  FKID
09-07-2021  1   1
09-07-2021  1   128
09-07-2021  2   1
09-07-2021  3   128
10-07-2021  4   1
10-07-2021  4   128
10-07-2021  1   1
10-07-2021  1   128
```

FINAL OUTPUT :-

```
DATE        FKID    RFLAG   DFLAG   BOTH
09-07-2021  1       1       1       1
09-07-2021  2       1       0       0
09-07-2021  3       0       1       0
10-07-2021  1       1       1       1
10-07-2021  4       1       1       1
```

i have try to implement following dax query.

DAX: -

```
TEMTABLE = 
GROUPBY(
    TABLE,
    TABLE[DATE],
    TABLE[FKID],
   "rflag", MAXX(CURRENTGROUP(),CALCULATE(TABLE,TABLE[fkID]=1),
   "dflag", MAXX(CURRENTGROUP(),CALCULATE(TABLE,TABLE[fkID]=128),
   "both",  MAXX(MAXX([rflag])=1 AND MAXX([dflag])=1)
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

PowerQuery solution:

```
let
    Source = Table.FromRows(Json.Document(Binary.Decompress(Binary.FromText("i45WMrDUNTDXNTIwMlTSUYLgWB1swkYWmBJG2NUbI6k3NECSMIGrxxTGpt4Qu3q4e2IB", BinaryEncoding.Base64), Compression.Deflate)), let _t = ((type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true]) in type table [DATE = _t, ID = _t, FKID = _t]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"DATE", type date}, {"ID", Int64.Type}, {"FKID", Int64.Type}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "rflag", each if [FKID] = 1 then 1 else 0),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Added Custom", "dflag", each if [FKID] = 128 then 1 else 0),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom1", {"DATE", "ID"}, {{"rflag", each List.Max([rflag]), type number}, {"dflag", each List.Max([dflag]), type number}}),
    #"Added Custom2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "both", each if ( [rflag] = 1 and [dflag] = 1 ) then 1 else 0)
in
    #"Added Custom2"
```

DAX solution:

```
Table 2 = 
ADDCOLUMNS ( 
    SUMMARIZE (
        'Table' , 
        'Table'[DATE], 'Table'[ID],
        "rflag", IF ( CONTAINS ( 'Table', 'Table'[FKID] , 1 ) , 1 , 0 ),
        "dflag", IF ( CONTAINS ( 'Table', 'Table'[FKID] , 128 ) , 1 , 0 )
    ),
    "both", IF ( [dflag] = 1 && [rflag] = 1 , 1 , 0 )
)
```